# como hacer que math random empiece desde un numero en concreto en javascript

Tags: javascript

El problema o la duda que tengo es como hacer para que empiece desde un numero por ejemplo esto haria lo siguiente

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*4 + 1);
```

Elige un numero de 1 a 4

> Pero ahora lo que quiero es empezar desde 4 hasta 8 por ejemplo como podria hacer esto es decir que cuente desde 4 hasta 8 eligiendo en lugar de un numero en solo este intervalo. Que debo hacer para poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Partiendo de la documentación de Mozilla Developer<sup>1</sup>, tenemos que:

- `Math.random()` genera un número entre 0 y 1
- `Math.round()` redondea un número al entero mas cercano, *útil si consideramos que los números devueltos por `Math.random()` van desde el 0 hasta el 1*

Si ahora hacemos:

```
console.log(Math.round(Math.random()))
```

Obtendríamos un número *aleatorio* entre 0 y 1 por que los decimales se están redondenado a su entero cercano.

Por ejemplo:

Si obtengo:

- 0.1, entonces `Math.round()` lo pasará a 0
- 0.5, entonces `Math.round()` lo pasará a 1

Ahora auxiliándonos de los ejemplos de la Mozilla Developer<sup>2</sup>, vamos a realizar lo siguiente:

> El resultado obtenido lo vamos a multiplicar por la resta de 8 menos 4 y sumando a ese resultado 4.

Por ejemplo como primer escenario, solo obtendremos un número aleatorio al que le multiplicamos el resultado se la resta y le sumamos 4:

```
console.log(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4)
```

Después de algunas repeticiones obtenemos algo como esto:

```
5.02284384682516
6.666274445857721
4.655480080047504
6.817561660942711
7.756693448703826
4.93978024024416
7.553764157777947
7.260355543367207
```

Ahora necesitamos redondear los valores obtenidos, hacemos esto:

```
let numero = Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4

console.log(Math.round(numero))
```

Después de una serie de repeticiones de la sentencia `console` la salida sería similar a esta:

```
5
6
5
8
4
8
6
5
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- <sup>1[Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round)</sup>
- <sup>1</sup>[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random)
- 2 [Ejemplo de número aleatorio entre un mínimo y un máximo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)